# possible memory leak in a singleton?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, producer-consumer

I've asked this question before with no real answer. Can anybody help?
I'm profiling the below code inside a singleton and found that a lot of Rate objects (`List<Rate>`) are kept in memory although I clear them.

```
protected void FetchingRates()
{
  int count = 0;

  while (true)
  {
    try
    {
      if (m_RatesQueue.Count > 0)
      {
        List<RateLog> temp = null;

        lock (m_RatesQueue)
        {
          temp = new List<RateLog>();
          temp.AddRange(m_RatesQueue);
          m_RatesQueue.Clear();
        }

        foreach (RateLog item in temp)
        {
          m_ConnectionDataAccess.InsertRateLog(item);
        }

        temp.Clear();
        temp = null;
      }
      count++;
      Thread.Sleep(int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RatesIntreval"].ToString()));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {  
      Logger.Log(ex);                 
    }
  }
}
```

The insertion to the queue is made by:

```
public void InsertLogRecord(RateLog msg)
{
  try
  {
    if (m_RatesQueue != null)
    {
      //lock (((ICollection)m_queue).SyncRoot)
      lock (m_RatesQueue)
      {
        //insert new job to the line and release the thread to continue working.
        m_RatesQueue.Add(msg);
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Logger.Log(ex);  
  }
}
```

The worker inserts rate log into DB as follows:

```
 internal int InsertRateLog(RateLog item)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand dbc = GetStoredProcCommand("InsertRateMonitoring");
            if (dbc == null)
                return 0;
            dbc.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@HostName", item.HostName));
            dbc.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RateType", item.RateType));
            dbc.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LastUpdated", item.LastUpdated));
            return ExecuteNonQuery(dbc);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Log(ex);
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Any one sees a possible memory leak?

Comment: Can you reformat this so code is easier to see please?

Comment: I don't know about memory leaks, but the way you're "handling" exceptions is extremely suspicious to start with.

Comment: please notice- all execptions are logged to file system with a generic logger. the code lines for it were removed.

Comment: @user437631 put them back in?

Comment: It would be better to simply remove the try..catch blocks.  Example code should be as simple as possible.

Comment: How do you know there is a memory leak?  Maybe the GC simply hasn't touched those objects yet.

Comment: Your locking seems error-prone. Not all accesses to m_ratesQueue are protected by the same monitor.

Comment: .NET 4's `BlockingCollection` would make this code much nicer (if .NET 4) is an option (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are not disposing of your `SqlCommand` which is hanging onto a RateLog.

Answer (score 2):

1. I hope you are properly disposing the ADO.NET objects. (This is simply good practice.)
2. Any stray references will keep your `RateLog` objects from being collected by the GC.

I recommend you look through your code starting where the `RateLog` objects are being created and take note of all the places a reference is being held. Here are some things to consider.

1. Are the `RateLog` objects subscribed to any events?
2. Are you keeping a collection of `RateLog` objects sitting somewhere in a static class?

You should also consider encapsulating all your thread safety boilerplate in class.

```
public sealed class WorkQueue<T>
{
    private readonly System.Collections.Generic.Queue<T> _queue = new System.Collections.Generic.Queue<T>();
    private readonly object _lock = new object();

    public void Put(T item)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            _queue.Enqueue(item);
        }
    }


    public bool TryGet(out T[] items)
    {
        if (_queue.Count > 0)
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                if (_queue.Count > 0)
                {
                    items = _queue.ToArray();
                    _queue.Clear();
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        items = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

This will make your code a lot clearer:

```
protected void FetchingRates()
{
    int ratesInterval = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RatesIntreval"].ToString());
    int count = 0;
    var queue = new WorkQueue<RateLog>();

    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            var items = default(RateLog[]);
            if (queue.TryGet(out items))
            {
                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    m_ConnectionDataAccess.InsertRateLog(item);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {  
            Logger.Log(ex);                 
        }

        Thread.Sleep(ratesInterval);
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm using an one open SqlConnection. should i dispose my SqlComamnd objects?do they keep refrence to my rate logs?

Comment: @user437631: Yes, you should. The general rule is: Everything that implements `IDisposable` also requires that you dispose it (or that at least someone does). Wrap your `SqlCommand` in a `using` statement: `using (SqlCommand dbc = GetStoredProcCommand("InsertRateMonitoring")) { /* do stuff */ }`

Comment: @user437631 - As @0xA3 said you should dispose of the command objects. The command objects themselves won't keep a reference to the `RateLog` object but you may be keeping a reference somewhere else in your code.

Comment: how can i force the rate log to the GC fter submitting it to the Database?

Comment: @user437631 - It is bad practice to try and force the GC to handle your code. Without more information it would be pretty hard to give you definitive advice.

Comment: what more information can i give? if i create my temp list of rates in the singleton- could this be the problem?

Comment: @user437631 - First properly dispose of your ADO.NET objects to see if that resolves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

How about moving the `temp` creation outside the loop.  You are probably not allowing the GC to clean up.

```
protected void FetchingRates()
{
  int count = 0;
  List<RateLog> temp = new List<RateLog>();

  while (true)
  {
    try
    {
      if (m_RatesQueue.Count > 0)
      {    
        lock (m_RatesQueue)
        {
          temp.AddRange(m_RatesQueue);
          m_RatesQueue.Clear();
        }

        foreach (RateLog item in temp)
        {
          m_ConnectionDataAccess.InsertRateLog(item);
        }

        temp.Clear();
      }
      count++;
      Thread.Sleep(int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RatesIntreval"].ToString()));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {                   
    }
  }
}
```

After `temp.Clear()` you might try adding `GC.Collect();`.  This should NOT be the permanent solution, but could be used for your profiling to see if the objects get cleaned up eventually.  If not, then there might still be a reference or event attached somewhere.

Comment: It actually should *not* matter whether the temp list is declared inside or outside the loop.

Comment: Right, its just a bit cleaner.  The *rest* of my answer addresses what the OP is seeing

Answer (score 0):

the Clear() function deconstructs the List. But what about the RateLog instances? Is their deconstructor called? What about the lock, maybe this prevents that the RateLog from beeing deleted.

Comment: what should i do?make them Idisposable and loop them and call dispose?

Comment: Depends on whats in the class... unmanaged objects? Objects that need to be disposed?, etc

Comment: no. very simple class with three string\date time\int properties.

Comment: In .NET there is no destructor that is explicitly called. There is a finalizer that is called by the garbage collector on objects that require finalization. It looks similar to a destructor, but is a different concept.